# angular "Expression has changed after it was checked error" using moment.js

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs

> Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '25 minutes ago'. Current value: '26 minutes ago'.

I am attempting to show `moment` based times in my angular 4 component.

#### Component Markup

```
<div class="float-right">
    <small *ngIf="!isInProgress(batch)" class="text-muted"  
    [textContent]="getMomentEndTime(batch)"></small>
</div>
```

#### Component

```
export class BatchStatusComponent {
@Input() batchStatuses: BatchStatus[];

constructor(
    private readonly logger: NGXLogger) {
}

isInProgress(batch) {
    var estimate = batch.percentCompleted || 0;
    return (estimate > 0 && estimate < 100);
}

getMomentEndTime(batch: BatchStatus) {
    return (batch.endTime)
        ? moment(batch.endTime).fromNow()
        : "";
}
```

*Clearly the value is changing as time progresses, so no surprises there?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error itself is harmless and indicates that something may go wrong on change detection. If this is expected, the error can be safely ignored.

The error is caused by the fact that the value has changed during change detection cycle. This can be improved by throttling the method:

```
throttledGetMomentEndTime = _.throttle(this.getMomentEndTime, 100);
```

Alternatively, the code can be refactored to use *pure* pipe to convert time to `... minutes ago` string, like `amTimeAgo` pipe from `angular2-moment` package.

The fact that it is possible to see this error more or less often may suggest that change detection cycles occur too often. Additionally, the amount of change detection cycles can be reduced by setting `OnPush` change detection strategy for the component, if it fits the case.